# javax.mail - force IMAP to use TLS1.2+ - "Received fatal alert: protocol_version"

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-mail, imap, sslcontext

I have problem with my app for reading mails over IMAP.

App reads multiple imap accounts. App can connect to all servers except one that require to use TLS1.2 or TLS1.3.

I have this code:

```
System.out.println("SSLContext getProtocols(): " + String.join(" ", SSLContext.getDefault().getSupportedSSLParameters().getProtocols()));

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.imap.auth", "true");        
props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");          
props.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "false");
props.put("jdk.tls.client.protocols", "TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3");
props.put("mail.imap.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect(mailConf.getImapServer(), mailConf.getImapServerPort(), mailConf.getImapUser(), mailConf.getImapPass());
Folder inbox = store.getFolder(mailConf.getImapMailFolder());
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
```

and run app using:

```
java -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3" \
-Ddeployment.security.SSLv2Hello=false \
-Ddeployment.security.SSLv3=false \
-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1=false \
-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.1=false \
-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true \
-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.3=true \
-jar myApp.jar
```

For IMAP server, that require TLS1.2+ I see this output:

```
SSLContext getProtocols(): TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1 SSLv3 SSLv2Hello
Jan 29 11:41:19 myhost myapp[22101]: 2020-01-29 11:41:19 ERROR e.v.MyAppApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8bb5321c:68 - Imap readMail() error: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
```

I'm using Java 11:

```
# java --version
openjdk 11.0.4 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Debian-1deb10u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Debian-1deb10u1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

What I do bad? How can I force TLS1.2+ for imap connection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution: upgrade Spring Boot from **2.1.1.RELEASE** to **2.2.4.RELEASE**.

Answer (score 2):

**For SMTP:**
mail.smtps.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2

**For IMAP:**
mail.imaps.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2

**For POP3:**
mail.pop3s.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2

Comment: mail.imap.ssl.protocols worked for me (without s in imaps)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `jdk.tls.client.protocols` property from the JavaMail properties since JavaMail is definitely not interpreting that property.  Setting it on the command line as a System property is fine since the JDK will interpret it.

I didn't see any documentation about the `deployment.security.*` properties, but what I did see suggests they're only relevant if you're using the Java Plug-In or Java WebStart, which you aren't.  So you probably don't need to set those properties.

The error message you're getting suggests that your app is using Spring, although I don't see it in the JavaMail code you posted.  Perhaps Spring is somehow interposing on the socket setup code and controlling the security configuration?

You can try the standalone JavaMail [msgshow.java](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/msgshow.java) sample program just to prove that you can make a connection using that JDK version with no special security configuration.  If that fails, the problem is in the JDK security configuration.